# num2[i] = rando.charAt(i); - эта строчка гробит всю функцию ran. Почему?

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var rando = 0;
  var numb;
  var huy = 0;
  var num = [];
  var num2 = new Array ();
  var Bull = 0;
  function  ran() {
    while (rando < 1000) {
    rando = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
  }
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    num2[i] = rando.charAt(i);
    alert(num2[i]);
    alert("Изиизизи");
  }
  document.getElementById('rand').innerHTML = rando;
  }
  function butt(){
    numb = document.getElementById("number").value;
    for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
      num[i] = numb.charAt(i);
      alert(num[i]);
      if (num2[i] = num[i]) {
        document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = Bull + "Б";
        Bull++;
      }
    }

  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Не стоит разводить дубли. Либо отредактируйте старый вопрос, либо удалите его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) - это метод строк, а rando у вас - число.
Воспользуйтесь методом [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) чтобы привести число к строке.

```js
var rando = 0;
var numb;
var huy = 0; // noob detected!
var num = [];
var num2 = new Array ();
var Bull = 0;
function  ran() {
  /* Это наркомания.
  while (rando < 1000) {
    rando = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
  }
  */
  rando = 1000 + Math.round(Math.random()*9000);
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    num2[i] = rando.toString().charAt(i);
    alert(num2[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('rand').innerHTML = rando;
}
function butt(){
  numb = document.getElementById("number").value;
  for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
    num[i] = numb.charAt(i);
    alert(num[i]);
    if (num2[i] = num[i]) {
      document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = Bull + "Б";
      Bull++;
    }
  }
}
ran();
```

```html
<input id=number />
<div id=rand></div>
<div id=game></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо братан!

Comment: @DenisSakhno https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers